# How to access child class method using parent class refrence?

Tags: java, inheritance, downcast, upcasting

I am getting error while accessing Child class method by using Parent class reference variable.
Please help me.

How can I access that method?

```java
class Parent 
{
    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println("Show method in Parent class");
    }
}
class Child extends Parent
{
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("Print method in Child class");
    }
}
public class Downcast
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Parent p1=new Child();
        p1.print();//showing error here
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler sees `p1` as a `Parent`, it has no `print()`, the *actual* runtime type `Child` does not matter.

Comment: You should also include the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Parent` class knows nothing about methods in your `Child` class. That's why you get error.

One of the possible solutions is to make your `Parent` class as abstract and add abstract `print()` method in it, but in this case all subclasses should override this method:

```
abstract class Parent {

    public void show() {
        System.out.println("Show method in Parent class");
    }

    public abstract void print();
}

class Child extends Parent {

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Print method in Child class");
    }

}

public class Downcast {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p1 = new Child();
        p1.print();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused since the `Parent` class knows nothing about the `Child` class. One way to fix the error is by doing an explicit cast `((Child) p1).print();`

Answer (score -1):

You can do a cast :

```
class Parent 
{
    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println("Show method in Parent class");
    }
}
class Child extends Parent
{
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("Print method in Child class");
    }
}
public class Downcast
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Parent p1=new Child();
        ((Child) p1).print();// Out : Print method in Child class
    }
}
```